# How to make navbar which would be under image?

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

My navbar (text) is other page but I would like to that it would be centrally under logo or image. My align-items doesn't work so I have to get height in class .logo Any other method to do it?

```
<header class="header" id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo/logo.png" alt="Logo Fim Produkcji">
        </div>
        <nav class="nav__menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#faq__section">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact__section">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery__section">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

[code](https://codepen.io/FilipoV/pen/KKWOqWw)

css

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: sans-serif;      
}
.header, .gallery__section{
  height: 100vh;
}
.gallery__section{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080);
}
header{
   background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.logo{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.logo img{
  max-width: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.nav__menu{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav__menu ul li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS is very important to add here too. Can you give an example of what you want to accomplish? Your Navbar is already under the logo. The offending CSS is: `.logo { height: 100%; }`, so it's doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the image's position fixed and it should work